# back button causing scroll to top

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following scenario,  a user is scrolled some wheres down a search page. They click on an item and after they are done viewing the item they hit the back button. The back button brings the user back to their exact location within the search page as it's suppose to. After a second, the page auto scrolls to the top of the search results. You can see this behavior in action cardaddy.com/forsale

I've spent a couple hours trying to figure this out with no success. I'm not aware of any js causing this issue either. Please feel free to take a look. Any suggestions would be great since this is destroying my ux

I though maybe the forward from my root domain to www.domain.com with godaddy.com may of been the cause, so i changed that behavior around to use amazons name server eliminating the forwarding. I thought I repaired the issue as it seem repaired on the desktop,  but it still seems to happen on mobile.

Comment: I suspect is scrolls back up to the top after a delay because focus is applied to the input box at the top of the page.

Comment: Interesting,  i never gave the focus a thought. Do you have any recommendations as to how I should go about fixing that? I'd imagine you would want the focus when coming to the page, but not on the back button. So how do u stop it on back?

Comment: Off the top of my head you might be able to check the history and see if the user cam from a search result, then apply the logic based on this value

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this behaviour depends on your browser.

The back button brings you to the last site you visited and loads this site new. So the effect to stay at the possition is caused by the browser engine.

Answer (score 0):

1 way of doing it would be to save the location of the page and restore to that location when back button is clicked
on click : `var position = $(window).scrollTop();`

On back button : `$(window).scrollTop(position);`